# how to fully statically compile a Qt Widgets project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt6, qtwidgets

Is it possible with visual studio to statically compile a QtWidgets project so that no dlls have to be shipped together with the executable file? How do I go about this?

Comment: Even if you could, you still have to ship your compilers run time libraries.

Comment: @JesperJuhl wouldn't just the .exe be enough?

Comment: Rarely. See fx https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

Comment: @JesperJuhl I frequently statically link MS Runtime Support `/MT` - _"Causes the application to use the multithread, static version of the run-time library."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=msvc-170

Comment: @RichardCritten Sure, that *is* an option. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: First you need buy a license, so your work would be legal. Otherwise you are violating LGPL license.